# How to regex match beginning and end of a file?

Tags: regular-expression

Using `/`, I want to be able to search for (and jump to) the beginning and end of the file I am in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`:h start-of-file`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#start-of-file) and [`:h end-of-file`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#end-of-file)

Patterns are, respectively, `\%^` and `\%$`.

Example:

```
/\%^I am on first line
```

Answer (score 0):

In very magic mode (`\v`), the patterns are respectively `%^` and `%$` (see `:help /\v` and `:help start-of-file`, scroll down for `:help end-of-file`).

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!